# Constant folding in the preprocessing stage

Tags: c, gcc, scripting, deobfuscation, constantfolding

I have a piece of C code I need to deobfuscate. It contains a bunch of tricky macros. I ran the code through C preprocessor and indent and now it looks similar to this:

```c
switch (9263 + 1505) {
case 1505 + 41131 + 6729 + 2347:
            ...
case 1505 + 41131 + 6729 + 2347 + 1:
            ...
case 1505 + 41131 + 6729 + 2347 + 2:
            ...
```

To simplify further analysis I am looking for some tool that can fold all the constants in the code. I know that C preprocessor is unable to do this and constant folding optimisation will be performed during compilation stage. But what about source code?

Shell scripts are appreciated as well, as I suspect this could be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use clang to compile it, and use its c backend to generate c code.

Something like this should work:

```
clang -emit-llvm source.cpp -o - | llc -march=c
```

Comment: As I can see, C as a backend for LLVM is no longer supported. I tried to use C++ instead, but the result is very different from the initial source.

Comment: Can you just pull an older clang from git and compile it yourself? The C backend does seem to be the best way to do it. Try a version from around Dec 2009. Otherwise, you'll have to hack the switch case statement (line 669) yourself: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Stmt_8h_source.html

Comment: I did it. Well, the final code is far from readable, but it is not so long and complicated anymore. So with the help of gdb I managed to deobfuscate it. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelZaichenkov could you please post your findings somewhere?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, if you are interested in the program itself, [here](http://pastebin.com/J4V5p14d) it is. The program sorts a list of numbers. Your goal is to understand what kind of sorting algorithm it uses.